# How to test url query string in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

How to test this.props.location.search from below code snippet.

I'm getting below error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

```
export class myView extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
}
});
```

I wanted to test values present in variable values.

Comment: can you present more code of the component so that it will be easy to solve it

Comment: check this out https://medium.com/@matthew.holman/testing-url-hash-query-with-jest-8165f26ab94e

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used @Praveen Rao Chavan.G suggestion, https://medium.com/@matthew.holman/testing-url-hash-query-with-jest-8165f26ab94e link helped to solve this.